How can I uniquely identify a component being rendered on a page?
I have a grid component that is saving its own state in localStorage. Currently, that grid component has a required prop named gridName. I use this gridName to build a key for use with localStorage.
It's becoming annoying to name ever single grid rendered throughout the application. I'm having developers asking me what to name every grid.
Is there a way to automatically uniquely identify this component wherever it may be rendered?
Like in C# I could potentially use something like Reflection to get a unique name for that rendering of the component. Anything like that?

I got that you want something random for a key. But are you also asking that the next time you open same page and same grid to get the same key as before? If this is what you want, useId won't give you this. It gives you unique string for a session. If you start your app on page A it will give you r:0, but if you start on page B, it will give you same r:0, because it is a new session. Instruments like useId will give you unique string each time, if you want the next time when you open something to get a same string as before, you have to manually set that.

1- Using useId Hook
React provides the useId hook to generate unique IDs. These IDs are consistent between server and client and are guaranteed to be unique within a React tree.
import React, { useId } from 'react';

const GridComponent = ({ gridName }) => {
   const uniqueId = useId();
   const storageKey = gridName || `grid-${uniqueId}`;

   // Save to localStorage
   console.log(storageKey); // Example: "grid-r:0"

   return <div>Your Grid</div>;
};

2-Using Component Location and Random ID
You can generate a unique key using the component's location in the React tree. For example, combining window.location.pathname and a Math.random() value:
const GridComponent = ({ gridName }) => {
const uniqueId = gridName || `grid-${window.location.pathname}-${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}`;

   // Save to localStorage
   console.log(uniqueId);

   return <div>Your Grid</div>;
};

This ensures that grids on different pages won't conflict.
3-Using React.createRef
f the grids are part of the same parent, you can use React.createRef to assign unique identifiers
4-Using Index and Parent Component Name
If the grid is part of a parent component that repeats multiple grids, you can use an index or parent name to make it unique
const ParentComponent = () => {
const grids = [/* grid data */];

return grids.map((grid, index) => (
    <GridComponent key={index} gridName={`parent-grid-${index}`} />
));
};

Recommendation
The useId hook is the most React-native and consistent solution. However, if you need uniqueness across pages or for debugging purposes, combining window.location.pathname with a random value or a hash of the grid props works well.

Ah, OK. Yea I would need uniqueness across pages. Thanks!
